# Why backgroundColor doesn't work with View in React Native?

Tags: react-native, styling

I'm trying to make a top menu and colorize it, but `backgroudColor` property doesn't work.

[How the app looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIpFS.png)

```
      <View>
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          height: 50,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
        }}>
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}><Text style={style.upMenu.text}>H</Text></View>
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}><Text style={style.upMenu.text}>Plugins</Text></View>
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}><Text style={style.upMenu.text}>Remote</Text></View>
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}><Text style={style.upMenu.text}>P</Text></View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

**Solved**

Thanks a lot, your answers both are very useful!

Comment: Can you `toggle inspector` and check your `View` style ?

Comment: what contains your `style.upMenu.text` ? maybe here is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give prop `flex:1`  to the parent view style.

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
  .....Child Views      
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the code below,

```
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        height: 50,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        backgroundColor: "#87ceeb",
        maxHeight: 20
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#87ceeb" }}>
        <Text style={style.upMenu.text}>H</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#87ceeb" }}>
        <Text style={style.upMenu.text}>Plugins</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#87ceeb" }}>
        <Text style={style.upMenu.text}>Remote</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#87ceeb" }}>
        <Text style={style.upMenu.text}>P</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

to get the required header height use the `maxHeight` to change it